# I want to create complete function of todo list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

when user click on checkbox todo list background become blue text decoration on list paragraph is line-through how i can to do this using javascript

**Javascript code**

```
function createlist()
{
   document.getElementById("tolist").insertAdjacentHTML ("afterend",`<div id="todolistcontainer">
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-list" onclick="complete()">  
   <p id="tasktodo"></p>
   <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-xmark" id="todoicon" onclick="deletelist()"></i>
   </div>`);
   document.getElementById("tasktodo").innerHTML=document.getElementById("input").value;

}
function deletelist()
{
    document.getElementById("todolistcontainer").remove();
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <title>To Do List JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
       <input type="text" id="input" >
       <button id="button" onclick="createlist()">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div id="tolist"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS code**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Code:wght@500&display=swap');
body{
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-right: 30%;
    font-family:fira Code;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 5px solid black;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.container #input{
    border: 0px solid black;
    width:100%;
    margin: auto;
    font-size:40px;
    
}
.container #input:focus{
    outline:none;
}
.container #button{
    border: 0px solid black;
    width:30%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    height:100%;
    font-size:40px;
}
#todolistcontainer{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:80%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top:12px;
    margin:auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 12%;
}
#tasktodo{
    font-size:150%;
    width:30%;
    align-self: center;
    margin: auto;

}
#checkbox-list{
    width:8%;
}
#checkbox-list:checked{
   accent-color: blue;
}
#todoicon{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-self: center;
    width:12%;
    font-size:50px;
}
```

**MY todo-complete javascript function**

```
function complete()
{

    if(document.getElementById("checkbox-list.parentNode").checked)
    {
        document.getElementById("tasktodo").style.textDecoration="line-through";
        document.getElementById("tasktodo").style.color="grey";
        document.getElementById("todolistcontainer").style.backgroundColor="blue";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("tasktodo").style.textDecoration="none";
        document.getElementById("tasktodo").style.color="black";
        document.getElementById("todolistcontainer").style.backgroundColor="white";
    }

}
```

**But output is not satisfied**

[image: output screenshot]

I am learning html dom and got stuck at this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinglish beat me to the punch - but I have one additional thing to add:

Instead of inline JS use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) on your list container to catch events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM. You can then check to see if the element that fired the event was a button, check its `checked` status, and then use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) to update the paragraph style.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const list = document.querySelector('.tolist');
const add = document.querySelector('.add');

add.addEventListener('click', createList);
list.addEventListener('click', handleList);

function createList(e) {
  const html = `
    <div class="todoContainer">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox completed">  
      <p class="tasktodo">${input.value}</p>
    </div>
  `;
  list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

function handleList(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.checkbox')) {
    const { checked, nextElementSibling: nes } = e.target;
    if (checked) {
      nes.classList.add('strike');
      nes.closest('.todoContainer').classList.add('blue');
    } else {
      nes.classList.remove('strike');
      nes.closest('.todoContainer').classList.remove('blue');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Code:wght@500&display=swap);.container,.container input{width:100%}.container .add,.container input{border:0 solid #000;margin:auto;font-size:30px}body{margin-left:30%;margin-right:30%;font-family:fira Code}.container{display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:center;border:5px solid #000;margin-bottom:10px}.container .input:focus{outline:0}.container .add{width:30%;background-color:#00f;color:#fff;height:100%}.todoContainer{border:1px solid #000;width:80%;height:100px;margin:12% auto auto;display:flex;flex-direction:row}.tasktodo{font-size:150%;width:30%;align-self:center;margin:auto}.checkbox{width:8%}.checkbox:checked{accent-color:blue}

.checkbox:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.strike { text-decoration: line-through; color: grey; }
.blue { background-color: lightblue; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text">
  <button class="add">Add</button>
</div>
<div class="tolist"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things to learn here:

- You can't use ID's more than once. Everytime you were adding a todolist item, it was using the same ID and your code would only ever affect the first instance of those IDs. Instead, use classes.
- Rather than use IDs and a whole bunch of 'getElementById', use relative paths. For example, you can send your `complete()` function a reference to the checkbox like this `onclick="complete(this)"`. Then in your function, you can find the container using [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) like this: `elem.closest('.todolistcontainer')`.
- Finally, don't make your life hard by manually changing styles - instead use classes. A single class for your checked state would do the trick. Then you can just turn on and off the class based on the checkbox

```js
function complete(elem) {
  let container = elem.closest('.todolistcontainer');
  if (elem.checked) container.classList.add('ischecked');
  else container.classList.remove('ischecked');
}


function createlist() {
  let todo = document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("tolist").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", `<div class="todolistcontainer">
   <input type="checkbox" onclick="complete(this)">  
   <p class="tasktodo">${todo}</p>
   <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-xmark" class="todoicon" onclick="deletelist(this)"></i>
   </div>`);
}

function deletelist(elem) {
  elem.closest('.todolistcontainer').remove();
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Code:wght@500&display=swap');
body {
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  font-family: fira Code;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container #input {
  border: 0px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.container #input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.container #button {
  border: 0px solid black;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.todolistcontainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 12%;
}

.tasktodo {
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 30%;
  align-self: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.checkbox-list {
  width: 8%;
}

.checkbox-list:checked {
  accent-color: blue;
}

.todoicon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-self: center;
  width: 12%;
  font-size: 50px;
}


/* NEW CSS */

.todolistcontainer.ischecked .tasktodo {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <button id="button" onclick="createlist()">Add</button>
</div>
<div id="tolist"></div>
```